# Use Product Descriptions from "All Stores Views instead of Default Store View"

Tags: product, magento-2.2.5, stores

I'm relatively new to Magento, I'm on version 2.2.5 . The product descriptions on my site are correct under the "**All Stores Views**" however those descriptions aren't being applied to the "Default Store View".

> I need the product descriptions to pull from the "**All Stores
>   Views**" otherwise I'd have to re-write about 1,000 product
>   descriptions. How can this be done?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make Description attribute to be global.
To do this. Go to

> Store -> Attributes -> Products

Search attribute with the label **Description** and open it

Expend **"Advanced Attribute Properties"**

and set **scope** to **"Global"**

After reindex, magento will get products descriptions from All Store View

**Note: After this, you would not change description in store view**